# Adding TextView above ListView items to scroll along ListView Items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm trying to add a View above a ListView in a ListFragment (My Fragment extend a ListFragment).

I'm using an Adapter to put items on the ListView.

What I cannot achieve, Is to put another View(In this case, a TextView would be fine), that appears above the List Items and scroll among them.

I tried changing the Fragment superclass to Fragment and adding a layout with a TextView and a ListView and the problem is that in that way, the TextView don't scroll alogn the ListView elements.

I also tried to add a ScrollView and put both the TextView and the ListView inside it but in that way, the ListView don't scroll.

I also tried to manually add an object to the ArrayAdapter of the ListFragment (It was the first attempt), and then change ListView Item Layout accordingly, but the problem is that it won't appear (I don't know why).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ListView.addHeaderView()`.

You can't do this in XML.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater li, ViewGroup vg, Bundle b)
{
    ViewGroup result = (ViewGroup) super.onCreateView(li, vg, b);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("lalala");
    ListView lv = result.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.addHeaderView(tv);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok! That works. But just visually!

The Data on the items is swapped. On the first item it's the data from the second List Item and on the List Header is the Data from the first List Item...

Comment: It depends on where you're getting the data from.  Your Adapter will only return the data it knows about.  If you call getAdapter() on the ListView, or use ListView.getItemAtPosition(), it will use its own internal adapter that knows to offset the item positions before calling your Adapter.

Comment: This is helping but as I said, not solving my problem, as it swaps the List Item data, from the first Item, to the List Header and from the second to the first, and so on, although visually it appears right.

I have a customized adapter that I set with setListAdapter(MyListAdapter); and adding to the first problem is the fact that I've to make the setListAdapter on the onResume ListFragment method. This makes that when I come back to this fragment from another fragment that was called, he tries to add the Header on the onResume method and then the application blows up.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what did u mentioned by ListView.getItemAtPosition and passing the addHeader to the onCreateView ListFragment method and I'll come back as soon as I finish trying out.

Don't worry about that, of course I'll accept your answer as correct as soon as I get my problem solved.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use the onCreateView() method to set your header.  That way it is only done once.  What I'm saying with the other stuff is, the ListView counts the header as the first item in the ListView, and the first item in your adapter becomes the second item in the ListView, etc.  This is normal.  If you use ListView.getItemAtPosition() or ListView.getListAdapter() it will take care of offsetting it for you.  If you are trying to get the data for any item by calling your adapter directly, you could always just subtract one yourself.

Comment: No, on CreateView doesn't work either, so just onResume. With that approach, using a custom Adapter is not possible. So it will not solve my problem =/

Thanks anyway! ;) If you got anymore tips I would appreciate!

Comment: I edited the answer to demonstrate how to use onCreateView() from a ListFragment.

Comment: Probably the best place to set your adapter is in onActivityCreated.

Comment: With what we've been discussing all the things worked out fine!

It was needed to set the Adapter on onActivityCreated(), and the layout for the whole screen (The View component plus the ListView) on the onCreateView().

On the Adapter, instead of using MyData (ArrayList of MyData object), I used ListView.getItemAtPosition(position) on the getView() of the Adapter. I also created a setter for the ListView on the Adapter, which I use on the ListFragment, on the onActivityCreated() before calling setListAdapter().

Thanks a lot for all the help =)